ESEF XHTML - schemaRef
Hi I am currently trying to learn how ESEF works and i have some questions about the link:schemaRef Element.
Please correct me when I am wrong at any point as I am still learning :)
In general the folder structure seems to look like this in the final format:
META-INF/
├─ taxonomyPackage.xml
├─ catalog.xml
reports/
├─ Esef.xhtml
www.mycompany.com/
├─ xbrl/
│  ├─ 2024/
│  │  ├─ mycompany_2024.xsd
│  │  ├─ mycompany_2024_def.xml
│  │  ├─ mycompany_2024_pre.xml
│  │  ├─ mycompany_2024_cal.xml
│  │  ├─ mycompany_2024_lab_de.xml
│  │  ├─ mycompany_2024_lab_en.xml

www.mycompany.com/xbrl/2024 contains the taxonomy.
The Esef.xhtml has a section link:schemaRef where a link to the taxonomy is given.
<link:schemaRef xlink:href="https://www.mycompany.com/xbrl/2024/mycompany_2024.xsd" xlink:type="simple"></link:schemaRef>

I would understand if behind the link you come to the xsd file online but thats never the case in those ESEF files I have seen so far so why - when the taxonomy is already there physically - the link is not like this:
<link:schemaRef xlink:href="../www.mycompany.com/xbrl/2024/mycompany_2024.xsd" xlink:type="simple"></link:schemaRef>

That would make more sense to me?!
Thanks in advance to anyone who can give me a solid answer for that :)

The official location of the taxonomy schemas (and linkbases) is their absolute URL, which makes them accessible online.
However, it would not be efficient to always download the files over and over again. For this reason, the packages contain a mapping between the absolute URL of a file and the local copy of it in the package zip.
You will find this mapping in META-INF/catalog.xml. That way, the XBRL processor can directly read the taxonomy files locally but knowing that they correspond to the online version.
Concretely, an XBRL processor that implements the taxonomy package specification will read the schemaRef URL, convert it to a local path with the catalog.xml mapping, and then read the local version in the zip.
And at the same time, a generic XML processor that wants to validate the instance file and that is not aware of the mapping mechanism will download the file online, ignoring the local schema file. It is less efficient, but does not break.

Thanks for the fast answer :)
I did that... having https://www.mycompany.com/xbrl/2024/mycompany_2024.xsd in the link:schemaRef and in my catalog.xml I had <rewriteURI rewritePrefix="../www.mycompany.com/xbrl/2024/" uriStartString="https://www.mycompany.com/xbrl/2024/"></rewriteURI>
There were complaints that the XBRL processor (AMANA XBRL Auditor) could not correctly access the taxonomy...

I am not familiar with AMANA, but perhaps this helps: did you directly open the .xhtml file, or did you zip the whole folder structure and open the zip file with AMANA? How to open report packages can vary depending on the software product, but I imagine trying to directly open the .xhtml file may not trigger "report-package mode" and ignore the catalog file.

Thats a good clue. I will test that
Thank you

In report-package mode is there a certian rule how the name of the xhtml file has to be? Because I generate two different xhtml files and I think that might come to problems because the program does not know which one to choose?

The detection of the report file is based on the extension. If there is a .xhtml file in the reports directory, then it should be recognized and parsed as a separate report no matter what its name is. Other allowed report extensions are .xbrl, .json, .html and .htm.

Another suggestion: you could try to rename the zip file with the extension .xbri, and add a file META-INF/reportPackage.json with the content {"documentInfo":{"documentType":"https://xbrl.org/report-package/2023/xbri"}} to make it an Inline XBRL report package. But this is assuming AMANA implements the specification.

I also noticed your directory structure does not have a top-level directory. It is required to have, in the zip file, a top-level directory (with any name) and below it, META-INF, reports, etc.

Thanks but I just didn't show it in my illustration.
The name of the zip doesn't matter, right?
Another issue I have now is that I get the error rpe:unsupportedReportPackageVersion... In the docs I can read that the reportPackage.json is not a "must have" if reportPackage.json is absent, the value https://xbrl.org/report-package/PER/2024-06-11 is used what makes it an unconstrained report package by default.
What else could provoke the error? (I dunno if I should open a new topic for that ?!?)

https://xbrl.org/report-package/PER/2024-06-11 corresponds to a document type that has not yet reached Recommendation status (Proposed Edited Recommendation) and that is subject to changes.
The current Recommendation is at https://www.xbrl.org/Specification/report-package/REC-2023-09-22/report-package-REC-2023-09-22.html
Perhaps you will also find the ESEF reporting manual useful (2.6.1, 2.6.2, 2.6.3): https://www.esma.europa.eu/sites/default/files/library/esma32-60-254_esef_reporting_manual.pdf
It recommends an .xbri extension (which imposes constraints on the content, see above).

Ok got it... But now I have to ask a stupid question once more: instead of "documentType": "https://xbrl.org/report-package/PER/2024-06-11" in my reportPackage.json what do I need to put in there? This is not really clear from the documentation...
just https://www.xbrl.org/Specification/report-package/REC-2023-09-22 or there are also examples where https://xbrl.org/report-package/2023 is used?

Since ESEF uses Inline XBRL, the most natural document type would be https://xbrl.org/report-package/2023/xbri to indicate that this is an Inline XBRL report package. It could be that ESEF also accepts unconstrained packages, but the ESEF reporting manual recommends the .xbri extension, which in turns specifically requires the .../xbri documentType. Also, the report package specification prefers the .xbri extension to the .zip extension for a single report. It is a bit like prefering .xlsx over .zip for an Excel file (which is, in fact, a zip file).

so I just need to zip the file and rename to myreport.xbri instead of  myreport.zip, but in fact it stays a zip archive? And adding the https://xbrl.org/report-package/2023/xbri documentType to the reportPackage.json?

Yes, exactly. The report package specification requires this document type for the xbri extension.

Ok thanks for your help. Solved some big question marks in my brain :)
